# Revival: Post is no longer available

Tags: bug, status-completed, revival-badge

I received two revival badges but one of them says 'Post is no longer available'.

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/837/revival?userid=61974

If the post was deleted why was I awarded the badge in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrency issue with the badge grant job, I went ahead and revoked the badges however the flair counts will be off until you get your next badge.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing the badge-awarding script runs back through all the posts and votes chronologically, awarding badges as they *would have been* gained had that badge always existed. Since badges are rarely rescinded once gained, you are allowed to keep them for posts that are subsequently deleted.

However, I'm not sure if this was by-design or a bug in the script.

**EDIT:** I guess it was an undesired effect, because it appears to have been corrected now. I myself had an extra Revival badge for a deleted post as well, but it is gone now.

Comment: +1, it was announced that the script would be run retroactively. If the Revival badge had existed from day one, OP would've gotten one before the post was deleted, and badges are almost never removed once earned.