# Wrong Badge Count

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When I check my profile on stackoverflow.com on the upper part (me logged in) it shows these
[image: 15 Badges]
badges, so there are 2 silver and 13 bronze. (15)

However, when I go down to the actual list I see there are only 14 badges.
[image]

So there's a math overflow!
Now this is a bug!

**EDIT:** Maybe this is related to my last badge Revival when it appeared as it was x2.
However, I could only see one of the posts, the other showed as not available.
Can anyone check this?

Comment: Man has a point. Can't be a caching issue either, the last badge is 2 days old

Comment: @Jeff I see you edited as Status-Completed, and also noted that the number is now correct on my SO account. Is this fixed then? On the next time the revival script runs no extra badge will be awarded and miscounted?

Comment: any badge count will be auto-fixed the next time you get a badge. there is nothing to do here.

Comment: @Jeff when a user gains a new badge, you could check if the badge isn't already there, and if it is you check if the badge allows more than one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the badge script ran to award people Revival badges, [it gave out a bunch for currently-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69226/revival-post-is-no-longer-available). These extra badges were subsequently removed, but the badge *counts* weren't changed. [According to waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69226/revival-post-is-no-longer-available/69290#69290) the counts should correct themselves when you get your next badge.

Comment: So this is a bug, how is it reported ?

Comment: @Gabriel: I'm not sure they're considering it a major enough bug to fix for everyone affected. They will probably just tell you to hold out until your next badge.

Comment: So on My next badge will the count auto arrange itself?

Comment: @Gabriel: It should, however it appears that they may have already fixed the badge count for you, so you don't have to wait after all. ;)

Answer (score 5):

To clarify, we now normalize badge counts daily -- so if they are off, for whatever reason, they will be fixed within 24 hours.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to check it first and not having to recount them? 

Wow @Jeff do your answers appear with automatic +1? LOL