# What happened to my gold [discussion] badge?

Tags: support, badges

The other day I was awarded the gold badge for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (here on MSO, of course). Today I no longer have the badge and the award is no longer in my activity list. However, I still have one gold badge next to my name.

Plausible causes:

1. Jeff hates me.
2. Welbog mistook it as a pat of butter for his waffles.
3. A bug caused the badge to be erroneously awarded or revoked, but did not update the badge count.

Is this a bug? Should I have received the badge? Is there a conspiracy at work here?

(Complaint: tag length restriction does not support [badges-we-dont-need-no-stinking-bages](/questions/tagged/badges-we-dont-need-no-stinking-bages)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you still have a silver discussion badge. Unlike "real"/"regular" badges, tag badges [do get revoked if their conditions are no longer met](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge/68395#68395). I think you got downvoted past the 1000-score threshold, or had a post deleted, or some such.

Comment: On top of this, as far as the discrepancy in the flair, badge counts are only updated when you earn a new badge.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize tag badges could be revoked. The downvote theory makes more sense than mine then.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/topusers) lists you as having only 999 upvotes, where 1000 is needed for the badge. I'm guessing you were prematurely awarded the badge, and then it was revoked somehow (maybe this was part of a larger badge awarding error that was corrected). The flair that lists our badge counts [seems to lag these kinds of updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/wrong-badge-count).

Be patient, you will probably get the badge next go around.

Comment: Argh, you beat me to the URL for the tag info page. Good work.