# Badge count is wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

[My profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett?tab=badges&sort=recent) shows the wrong badge count. [A similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69452/195862) on Meta shows it was due to a temporary bug, but I've only been a member for 6 months, so this is something new I guess...

[image: badge]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Badges count on Badges tab means total *types* of badges you have earned. While in your profile (next to your reputation) it shows total *numbers* of badges you have earned.

In Badges tab it does not count multiple badges more than once.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be that. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can, thanks!